# Steps to include a Library from github into my project prior to compiling and publishing?

Tags: android, apk, android-library

As the title suggests, I'm using a library from github in my App.
In AndroidStudio, I simply enter the address for the repository into my Gradle file as dependency.

But when it comes time to compile and actually **publish** my App to the PlayStore, what must I do?
Some Libraries on GitHub have links to a JAR or AAR file, but many other do **NOT**.

**Bottom Line:** How to make sure a github library stays working in my App, prior to publishing?
In the case that a github Library simply references a repository address, what must I do?

Thanks all.

Comment: no need to bother much, you can use the dependency in gradle then build apk and check whether it is functioning properly or not, if yes then you can publish the same in play store. thank u

Comment: @Varma That's what I'm worried about - if the Library gets taken offline, or changed - and then I need to update my App at some point, but the Library is no longer available, or has been changed and broken my App somehow.. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.  If you've added it as a gradle dependency, it will be in the apk.

Comment: @gabe-sechang But what will happen if the author of the Library decides to take it offline? or changes it? Then when I need to update my App or something, wouldn't this cause issues? Is there a way to "permanently" grab the current version of the Library, and include it in my App manually, so I don't have to worry about these circumstances?

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns The libraries are not downloaded by each individual client-  the apk you upload holds the library inside of it.  So that's not a problem.  If your worry is about building future versions of your app, then you can clone or fork the repo.

Comment: Thats exactly what my worry is - for building future versions of my App successfully using the existing Library.. But if I do as you suggest and Fork the Repo, isn't that essentially the same as downloading the Zip? Or is there a way to obtain the proper file needed, for easy placement in a Libs folder of my App package, which I can include easily, and not require a bunch of coding changes?

Comment: In your gradle cache files you should find an already dowloaded jar or aar file for the library, you can just grab that.  Although I'd assume if you were worried enough about the availability of the library to do this, you probably want it as source-  what if it has C libraries and you need to recompile for a new ABI?  Or you want it compiled for Java9 in the future when android supports it?

Comment: First, thank you for continuing to reply, I appreciate it.. But I'm still *fairly* new to some of this stuff, and still learning many topics - included, being the topic at hand, which I have only ever used a simple 1-line gradle compile line to include. So again, I frankly don't have a clue as to how to go about this - I am simply trying to protect my App, in the event that the Repo goes offline, or changes in a way that breaks my code, so that future updates of my App have no worries. Plainly put, what do you recommend I do to accomplish this, specifically, again, still learning!

Comment: Changes in a way that would break your code-  use an exact version number.  Then that can't happen.  That's best practices anyway, you always want to make sure you test and release an individual version.  Honestly repos going offline I don't worry too much about.  Of course I don't include a library unless its actually needed, and if one disappeared I'd put in the effort to write my own version.  The libraries that are big enough I can't do that are very unlikely to disappear, and I'll figure that out if it happens.

Comment: ....I guess what I'm asking, straight forward, is, A) what do *most* people do when including a jitpack address or something in their build file for a Repo on github when it comes time to publish their App, as a safeguard against future deletion/changes in Repo? and B) what steps need to be taken to do that? eg: go (somewhere), do/download (something), place it (somewhere specific) in my App, maybe save a backup on my harddrive just in case, etc)? Again, I understand I can just include the Repo address in my gradle file for now, but I want to safeguard somehow. Thanks for patience

Comment: Again, I'm still *somewhat* new, and still learning, so if a Repo does happen to go offline or change and break my App, "figuring it out if it happens" or "coding it myself" isn't always going to be an easy solution for me, you know? I guess the solution I was looking for is something along the lines of A) simply including the most recent version of Repo jitpack address etc in my build gradle file (for now), meanwhile, saving a backup on my harddrive each time I make an update to my App, just in case (eg: whatever I would need to put in my App, if Repo disappears/breaks).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190551/discussion-between-studio2bdesigns-and-gabe-sechan).